# Detect when scrollable div is "focused" in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, html, scroll

Firefox has a behavior where, if you click on a scrollable `div`, then that div responds to all the mousewheel and the Page Up/Down keys, effectively making it "focused". However, the HTML5 spec dictates that `divs` *cannot* be "focused", technically. Therefore, even though the `div` receives keyboard and mouse events, it's not reported in `document.activeElement` or a `DOMActivate` event handler.

So how can I detect when a scrollable `div` has scrolling focus in Firefox? Here's a [test page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6173284/testscroll.html). Oddly, the `div` *is* reported in `document.activeElement` when you tab into it, but that's the only time that happens. A workaround might be to listen for `click` and `scroll` events instead, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution?

EDIT: This is for a Firefox extension, so any chrome-level JS would be acceptable. This also means I can't edit or predict how certain pages are coded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you assign the `<div>` a `tabindex` attribute/property (you can set it to `0` to make it focusable in the normal flow of the document, or `-1` to remove it from the normal tab flow entirely), then it can fire `focus` and `blur` events. Some simple CSS can eliminate the `outline` if you find it undesirable, but it may be desirable for usability reasons.

Comment: Yep, that did it! I'd vote you up if I had more rep. Though, I didn't mention that this is for a Firefox extension, so I'm working with pages that don't do this, for the most part.

Comment: Well if you are making an extension can you not just have the extension add the tabindex property?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be easy. I just wasn't sure if that was acceptable for an extension. At least this solution works, so I'll mark it as such! (P.S. I need to find another solution, since I don't want to add elements to the user's tab order.)

Comment: @Marco, See my edit. If you set `tabindex` to `-1` it is not in the tab flow.

Comment: This works for tab navigation, but use can still click in and have it receive "focus".

Comment: Adding `theScrollableDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { e.preventDefault() });` appears to prevent focusing by mouse click, so that combined with `tabindex="-1"` should prevent focusing by both keyboard and mouse.